# change animation automatically in android studio

Tags: android, animation

I try to do something like when I click a button, it will run an animation and then it will change to another different animation once the 1st animation is finish. I'm using animation-list for the animation.

I am using if else to change the animation but how to implement another animation in the 1st condition?

```
if(i == 0)
{
    //if 1st time click the button, it will transform from fattest to fat...
    transformAnimation.start();
    i++;
}
if(i == 1)
{
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.transform_2);
    transformToSlim = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    transformToSlim.start();
    i++;
}
else if(i == 2)
{
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.transform_3);
    transformToSlimmest = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    transformToSlimmest.start();
}
}
```

Comment: You should start other animation when the first animation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work for you:

```java
transformAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        transformToSlim.start();
    }
});
transformToSlim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        transformToSlimmest.start();
    }
});
```

This adds listeners to your animations that will trigger the next animation if the current one ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to start a second animation when first one finishes:

```
Animation animation1 = ...;
animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        Animation animation2 = ...;
        animation2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
animation1.start();
```